# Create multiple PDF's with python Reportlabs and 1 CSV

Tags: python, reportlab

Im new to python, and would be really grateful if some one could offer some advice or point me in the right direction. I have 1 large CSV file, with many order numbers and order lines.  (1 order many have many order lines, but the file consists of all orders from last 24 hours)
Im trying to create multiple PDF's  which has been grouped by the order number showing the lines. (one pdf for each order)
I found a great tutorial on Utube to show me how to add the group / create multiple files (mark2741-generate certificates) It looks great  because i have added order address and a logo to the canvas.  But i cant add a table to the canvas based on the group to show the order lines.
any ideas?

ps, Im using ReportLabs

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: you can opt for https://pypi.org/project/fpdf/ `fpdf library`, it has much customization of generating pdf with required shape,

https://pyfpdfbook.wordpress.com/2015/03/22/table-using-only-cell-borders/